# How can I make a query completely SQL-injection-safe with PDO?

Tags: php, pdo, sql-injection

Well, I've been reading 2 hours about mysql_real_escape() and addslashes() and stuff, but my  question is: how can I do this to work with PDO and be completely safe?

Comment: If you use PDO, you will not need `mysql_real_escape_string()`. It would probably be best if you could show an example of what you're trying to do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php). Example:

```
// $pdo = new PDO(...);
$query = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM table WHERE name = ?');
$query->execute(array($_GET['name'])); // Replaces ? with the
                                       // value in $_GET['name']
```

You don't have to worry about manually escaping any user inputed data, such as `$_GET['name']` in the example above.